# CodeIgniter CRUD form validation

Tags: php, validation, form, codeigniter

I've developed a crud "helper" of sorts. Fields/columns are derived from the database and contain everything from the name of the field to the type and size of the field. Part of the system integrates [CodeIgniter's form validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html) library. In the particular function in question, a field object is passed to the function and the following happens:

1. The system automatically adds validation requirements based on the field object. For example, whether or not the field is required (db says field cannot be null), if the db field has a `max_length` constraint .etc.
2. If the user has specified a set of validation rules themselves we first check to see if we have already set the rule (in 1) and as a special requirement we check to see if the user specified `max_length` is not greater than the `max_length` defined by the db. If that is the case, we use the db one. 
   *Note: user rules come in as a pipe-separated string, so we have to split it to get it as an array.*
3. We then generate a pipe-separated string that CI form validation can understand.

**The problem is, I think there might be a better way to do this. It seems rather messy having to convert the user validation rules into an array and then back intro a string. And the solution for `max_length` doesn't seem ideal. I need help with refactoring.**

Code works 100% btw.

Usage:

```
if (($rules = $this->field_validation_rules($field)) !== false) {
    $this->CI->form_validation->set_rules($field->name, $field->human_name, $rules);
}
```

Function:

```
/**
 * Gets validation rules for a field
 * 
 * Combines system rules and user rules
 * 
 * Required enforced if column cannot be null
 * 
 * Max length enforced for columns with max length attributes, overridden
 * by user max length of a smaller value than that which the db specifies
 * 
 * In list enforced for columns with type enum (if the field has user specified
 * in_list it will be removed as db one takes precedence)
 * 
 * @param obj $field
 * @return boolean|string
 */
protected function field_validation_rules($field) {
    $sdata = array();
    if (!$field->null) {
        $sdata['trim'] = 'trim';
        $sdata['required'] = 'required';
    }
    if (!is_null($field->max_length)) {
        if ($field->db_type == 'enum') {
            $sdata['in_list'] = implode(',', $this->get_enum_options($field));
        } else {
            $sdata['max_length'] = $field->max_length;
        }
    }
    if ($field->db_type == 'int') {
        $sdata['integer'] = 'integer';
    } elseif ($field->db_type == 'numeric') {
        $sdata['numeric'] = 'numeric';
    }
    $urules = array();
    if (isset($this->validation_rules[$field->name])) {
        if (count($sdata) == 0) {
            return $this->validation_rules[$field->name];
        } else {
            $urules = explode('|', $this->validation_rules[$field->name]);
            foreach ($urules as $index => $rule) {
                $f_rule = preg_filter('/\[(.*?)\]/', '', $rule);
                if (empty($f_rule)) {
                    $f_rule = $rule;
                }
                if (in_array($f_rule, array_keys($sdata))) {
                    if ($f_rule == 'max_length') {
                        if (preg_match('/\[(.*?)\]/', $rule, $matches) && intval($matches[1]) > $field->max_length) {
                            unset($urules[$index]);
                        } else {
                            unset($sdata['max_length']);
                        }
                    } else {
                        unset($urules[$index]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $srules = array();
    foreach ($sdata as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == $val) {
            $srules[] = $key;
        } else {
            $srules[] = $key . "[{$val}]";
        }
    }
    $rules = array_merge($srules, $urules);
    if (count($rules) !== 0) {
        return implode('|', $rules);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note: `$this->validation_rules[$field->name]` contains the user defined rules for the field (if any).**

Comment: Please don't judge me by this code :) It is the ugliest thing I've ever written... (unless you count procedural days).

Comment: `field_validation_rules($field)` is clearly part of a class. A little more info on that class would be helpful. I ask because it seems to me that your function might be more useful and easier to implement if it was added to  the `CI_Form_validation` class. It's hard to tell if that make sense without knowing what else is going on.

Comment: I looked into that once but the problem with that approach is I'd still have to do it a similar way as the form validation library doesn't split the string into an array and assign it to a class property. All of the processing is done in like one function  I believe. I don't feel like hacking into or extending the core. The class above that this function is a part of is an intermediary or base class. It extends a fields class which fetchs the fields from the database and each field is a part of the fields object where the current values and rules are added onto. This function is part of the fo

Comment: Form validation system

Comment: OK, that is kind of what I expected. Something you might find most helpful is looking at the definition of `set_rules` in system/libraries/Form_validation.php. You will find that the `$rules` argument can be an array and, when a string is supplied, it is converted into an array. It's actually more efficient to pass rules as an array. With that in mind I think you will find your function can be greatly simplified.

Comment: After re-reading your previous comment I'd like to add that not only is the `$rules` string converted to an array it is assigned to a class property - `_field_data['rules']`. Perhaps another reason to reconsider extending the core class? It's not hard to do.

Comment: "when a string is supplied, it is converted into an array." ok so let's say I provide an array which I guess would be like `array('required', 'min_length[123]')`? How does one handle the rules with additional parameters e.g. `min_length` above.

Comment: It is done exactly as you show in the comment. See the Note at the end of the documentation section on [Cascading Rules](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#cascading-rules)

Comment: A clarification on my comment about the class property: The property `_field_data` is an array where the index is the name of the field. So instead of simply `_field_data['rules']` it should have been `_field_data[$field]['rules']` where `$field` is the name of the field.